# XSLT copy all nodes and add node to loop

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to compare quantity and add status, but my XSLT is not working. Why?
I would not want to rebuild the element /root/SG0/SG26/
I have tried many options, but all to no avail

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <InterchangeHeader>InterchangeHeader</InterchangeHeader>
    <SG0>
        <UNH>UNH</UNH>
        <BGM>BGM</BGM>
        <DTM>DTM</DTM>
        <SG26>
            <LIN>
                <E1082>000010</E1082>
                <C212>
                    <E7143>SRV</E7143>
                </C212>
            </LIN>
            <PIA>
                <E4347>1</E4347>
                <C212>
                    <E7140>000010</E7140>
                    <E7143>IN</E7143>
                </C212>
            </PIA>
            <QTY>
                <C186>
                    <E6063>21</E6063>
                    <E6060>2100.000</E6060>
                    <E6411>EA</E6411>
                </C186>
            </QTY>
            <QTY>
                <C186>
                    <E6063>170</E6063>
                    <E6060>2100.000</E6060>
                    <E6411>EA</E6411>
                </C186>
            </QTY>
        </SG26>
        <SG26>
            <LIN>
                <E1082>000020</E1082>
                <C212>
                    <E7143>SRV</E7143>
                </C212>
            </LIN>
            <PIA>
                <E4347>1</E4347>
                <C212>
                    <E7140>000020</E7140>
                    <E7143>IN</E7143>
                </C212>
            </PIA>
            <QTY>
                <C186>
                    <E6063>21</E6063>
                    <E6060>2100.000</E6060>
                    <E6411>EA</E6411>
                </C186>
            </QTY>
            <QTY>
                <C186>
                    <E6063>170</E6063>
                    <E6060>0.000</E6060>
                    <E6411>EA</E6411>
                </C186>
            </QTY>
        </SG26>
        <SG26>
            <LIN>
                <E1082>000030</E1082>
                <C212>
                    <E7143>SRV</E7143>
                </C212>
            </LIN>
            <PIA>
                <E4347>1</E4347>
                <C212>
                    <E7140>000030</E7140>
                    <E7143>IN</E7143>
                </C212>
            </PIA>
            <QTY>
                <C186>
                    <E6063>21</E6063>
                    <E6060>2100.000</E6060>
                    <E6411>EA</E6411>
                </C186>
            </QTY>
            <QTY>
                <C186>
                    <E6063>170</E6063>
                    <E6060>1900.000</E6060>
                    <E6411>EA</E6411>
                </C186>
            </QTY>
        </SG26>
        <UNS>
            <E0081>S</E0081>
        </UNS>
    </SG0>
    <InterchangeTrailer>InterchangeTrailer</InterchangeTrailer>
</root>
```

**my xslt** In the first part, I copy everything, and then I try to change

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:ext="urn:ext" exclude-result-prefixes="ext msxml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match='/root/SG0/SG26/LIN'>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="/root/SG0/SG26/QTY/C186[E6063='170']/E6060 = 0.000">
                    <status>1</status>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="/root/SG0/SG26/QTY/C186[E6063='170']/E6060 != /root/SG0/SG26/QTY/C186[E6063='21']/E6060">
                    <status>2</status>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="/root/SG0/SG26/QTY/C186[E6063='170']/E6060 = /root/SG0/SG26/QTY/C186[E6063='21']/E6060">
                    <status>3</status>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <status>3</status>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

** Desired XML result ** I would like to add a status for each position

```
...
<SG26>
    <LIN>
        <E1082>000010</E1082>
        <C212>
            <E7143>SRV</E7143>
        </C212>
        <status>3</status>
    </LIN>
    ...
</SG26>
<SG26>
    <LIN>
        <E1082>000020</E1082>
        <C212>
            <E7143>SRV</E7143>
        </C212>
        <status>1</status>
    </LIN>
    ...
</SG26>
<SG26>
    <LIN>
        <E1082>000030</E1082>
        <C212>
            <E7143>SRV</E7143>
        </C212>
        <status>1</status>
    </LIN>
    ...
</SG26>
```

Comment: Why is your last result (under `<E1082>000030</E1082>`) `<status>1</status>` and not `<status>2</status>`?

Comment: Exactly, I was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LIN">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <status>
            <xsl:variable name="v" select="../QTY/C186[E6063='170']/E6060" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$v = 0">1</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$v != ../QTY/C186[E6063='21']/E6060">2</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>3</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </status>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but the result is different from the one you show.